# How to send multiple mails at a given time by multiple users in Rails using delayed_jobs or any other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am using delyed_jobs mechanism for sending the emails. I got a requirement where a new field named "send_reports_at" has to be added and 
when user clicks on it, the calendar control will open with date and time and if user selects the email has to be delivered at so and so time.

Many suggested me to use schedulers and cron jobs, but I am totally new to that. With some R & D, I used run_at functionality with delayed_jobs.
I don't know whether it is right way or not, as multiple emails are sent at a time. But it used to work previously, not it is not.
This is my controller code:

```
def send_report_email
    send_to_agents = params.has_key?("send_to_agents") && params["send_to_agents"] == "true"
    if @report.update_attributes(params[:report])
      set_photo_position(false)
      @report.save

      @good_emails.each do |email|
        if @report.send_reports_at ==""
          ReportMailer.delay.additional_emails(email, @user, @report)
        else
          report_time = Time.zone.parse(@report.send_reports_at).utc
          ReportMailer.delay(run_at: report_time).additional_emails(email, @user, @report)
        end      
      end
      ReportMailer.delay.report_sent(@user, @report, @good_emails, @bad_emails, @unsubscribed_emails)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => { :success => true, :report_id => @report.id, :redirect => user_reports_url(current_user), :notice => 'Report was successfully sent!' } }
    end
```

end

Please help how to continue with this?

Answer (score 0):

Do not loop **@good_mails**. Send all good mails in a single delayed job task. Change the logic inside method **additional_emails** to receive array of @good mails and loop over there.

```
def send_report_email
  send_to_agents = params.has_key?("send_to_agents") && params["send_to_agents"] == "true"
  if @report.update_attributes(params[:report])
   set_photo_position(false)
   @report.save
    if @report.send_reports_at ==""
      ReportMailer.delay.additional_emails(@good_emails, @user, @report)
    else
      report_time = Time.zone.parse(@report.send_reports_at).utc
      ReportMailer.delay(run_at: report_time).additional_emails(@good_emails, @user, @report)
    end      
    ReportMailer.delay.report_sent(@user, @report, @good_emails, @bad_emails, @unsubscribed_emails)
  end

 respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => { :success => true, :report_id => @report.id, :redirect => user_reports_url(current_user), :notice => 'Report was successfully sent!' } }
 end
end
```

I hope this helps.